# Reduce multiple consecutive equal characters from a string to just one

Tags: c#, regex, linq, replace

Basically, I want to take a string, and if there are multiple '+'s in a row, i want to remove all but one. So:

```
"This++is+an++++ex+ampl++e"
```

would become

```
"This+is+an+ex+ampl+e"
```

I'm not sure whether LINQ or Regex or something else would be best suited, but it doesn't have to use any particular method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\++", "+");
```

Comment: Won't the result of that regex would just be `"This+is+an++ex+ampl+e"`?  It'll replace every ++ with +, but won't fix +++ or ++++ (etc) to +.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sammy_winter: No; `+` is a modifier.  (which is why I need a backslash)

Comment: To elaborate, the first `+`, which is escaped, means the actual plus character, the second `+`, means "one or more of the previous character". So, it will match one to any number of plus-es in a row, and replace them with a single plus. Which is what you want.

Comment: Probably wouldn't have a measurable effect on speed, but I'd do `\+\++` so that I only bother replacing where there's more than one `+`.

Comment: @slaks Ah right.  I need to use regexes more often so I don't have to make a fool of myself like this. :)

Comment: @TimS. If you're going to do all that, why not `\+{2,}`?  I feel like we're splitting hairs here, but as far as maintainability goes, I find  `\++` much more readable than either of our answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (str.Contains("++"))
    str = str.Replace("++", "+");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this with less code (and @slaks showed me how much I need to relearn regex), but this should close to as fast as is possible in most cases, if you're doing it a lot.

```
public static string RemoveDupes(this string replaceString, char dupeChar){
    if(replaceString == null || String.Length < 2){ return replaceString; }
    int startOfGood = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int x = 0;x<replaceString.Length-1;x++){
        if(replaceString[x] == dupeChar && replaceString[x+1] == dupeChar){
            result.Append(replaceString.SubString(startOfGood,x-startOfGood));//I think this works with length 0
            startOfGood = x+1;
        }
    }
    result.Append(replaceString.Substring(startOfGood,
                   replaceString.Length-startOfGood));
    return result.ToString();
}
//Usage: 
var noDupes = "This++is+an++++ex+ampl++e".RemoveDupes('+');
```

Comment: Whereas this appears to be faster than regex (at least on the test string), it has a fatal flaw. You get an index out of range exception with the string `"This++is++a++test++"`

Comment: @JimMischel True.  I fixed it to account for strings that start or end with ++.

Comment: To make it as fast as possible, you should pre-size the StringBuilder.

Comment: There's a cleaner and slightly faster solution. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/13/regular-expressions-optimization-and-practicality/. But unless I really needed the speed, I'd just use the regex.

Comment: @SLaks True, presizing the StringBuilder with the size of the starting string would be slightly faster in most cases (the exception being a long string that is mostly dupes), but this seemed good enough to be faster than regex.  Either way, I think your regex solution is better in over 90% of cases, I just like thinking about speed.

Comment: @JimMischel Nice post.  I'll admit that's about the level of performance gain I was expecting and I agree that the simplicity of the regex is better in most cases.  That's true often with modern computers, improving performance by multiple orders of magnitude is often unnecessary (and a waste of time) because the CPUs are fast enough.  It can still be fun to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Interactive Extensions (Ix)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27203) have a method called `DistinctUntilChanged` that does what you want. There is a bunch of useful functionality included in that library - but it *is* another whole library, which you might not want to bother with.

The usage would be like this:

```
str = new string(str
    .ToEnumerable()
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .ToArray());
```

If you want to remove only plus signs, then you could do this:

```
str = new string(str
    .ToEnumerable()
    .Select((c, i) => new { c, i = (c != '+' ? i : -1) })
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Select(t => t.c)
    .ToArray());
```

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? It's a perfectly legitimate solution, using a Microsoft extension library that will very likely be included in a future version of .NET.

Comment: Probably because we didn't use one line solutions, and using regex here creates cleaner looking code.  But I'm not sure why I got the downvote either.

Comment: Yeah but downvote is for *incorrect* answers, answers that *mislead*, or generally answers that are *not useful*. I personally dislike Regex (along with lots of other people I'm sure), and this presents a LINQ-style alternative. Downvote abuse is so prevalent on SO it's annoying...

Comment: I like regex for relatively simple cases like this, but it is almost never the fastest way to do something.  I think both of our answers, while they involve more code, might be faster, and seem correct and relevant.  Maybe downvotes should require a comment explaining the downvote.